# Im reading a csv file with 30 lines but only printing 29 in shell

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file im reading from and returning a column of data.  There is 30 rows of data and when I print the data I'm only getting 29.

```
def readMonth(fileName):
infile = open(fileName,"rb")
reader = csv.reader(infile)

month = []
for i in range(0,29):
    data = next(reader)
    month.append(int(float(data[25])))
infile.close()

return month
```

When I print I should have 30 lines not 29.  What do I need to change in order to print all 30 lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in range(0,29):
```

This starts at 0 and ends at 28. Did you mean `range(30)`? Though I'm not sure why you're not just looping over the `reader`.

Comment: When I do range(30) I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    month = readMonth("OshawaWindRemake2.csv")
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\Charlies Lab\lab11.py", line 12, in readMonth
    data = next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: You sure the file has 30 lines, then?

Comment: The final line may also need to be terminated with a newline, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import csv

def readMonth(fileName):
    infile = open(fileName,"r")
    reader = csv.reader(infile)

    month = []
    for row in reader:
        month.append(int(row[0]))
    infile.close()

    return month

month = readMonth('foo.csv')

print(month)
```